# Convolve function: Apply different radius in Gaussian filter

Tags: delphi, gaussian, convolution

There is convolve function in [swissdelphicenter.ch](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1704), you set your kernel and the resulting image will be blurred, but there is no parameter to apply more blur unless call the function multiple times (not desired coz of performance issue).

How to apply more blur to the image like Radius parameter in Photoshop Gaussian filter?

I am using this kernel to apply gaussian filter:

1    2    1
2    4    2
1    2    1

Comment: SuperUser is more appropriate for non-coding questions.

Comment: @SAMPro There's no code here. Are you just interested in knowing the algorithm? If not, and you want code, why aren't you using one of the quality graphics libraries such as graphics32. You are wasting your time with the website to which you linked which is full of low quality and ancient code.

Comment: Check out ongoing class from Duke on Coursera.

Comment: @David Heffernan , I use Delphi here for testing purpose only, final target is an embedded device so I must avoid libraries.

Comment: No reason whatsoever for you not to use graphics32. It's just code. Why does it matter who writes it? You just compile it and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make larger Gaussian kernel - 5x5, 7x7 etc. But performance will decrease proportional to Size^2. For some kernel size it is faster to use an approach with  FFT-based convolution.

**Edit**
FFT-based convolution: You have data array A, array with kernel values K (same length, zero-padded).

```
Conv(A, K) = BackFFT (FFT(A) * FFT(K))
```

To make convolution, one can

```
find Fourier transform of data
find Fourier transform of kernel
multiply them element-by-element (note that numbers are complex)
make inverse Fourier transform of product
get real part of it
```

Look at *Fast convolution algorithms* section in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) and part 13.1 of [Numerical recipes](http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.php) (almost practical manual)

If you are really interesting in fast treatment of many images, I'd recommend to use some dedicated library. For example, OpenCV is very fast ([Delphi wrapper exists](https://github.com/Laex/Delphi-OpenCV) for 2.4.11 version), Graphics32, ImageEn etc.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late reply. You right about libraries but because of my final target (an embedded device) I don't use any libraries. Can you give me a brief description about FFT-based convolution?

Comment: Short description added, but for proper using I'd recommend to read some DSP book.